# How to decrease a variable to zero?

Tags: python, thread-sleep, decrement

I have a variable inputted by any user to my program.
The task I cannot get to work is I want the variable to decrease from the input value to 0 over the course of a variable time (also input by the user). In pseudocode that would be something akin to:

```
x = time_variable
y = decreasing_variable
z = amount_of_decrease_of_y
while i < x:
    y = y - z;
```

I have tried writing the code, but it doesn't work properly:

```
time_of_activity = float(input('How long should health decrease in hours? '))
time_of_activity = time_of_activity * 60 * 60
health = float(input('How much is starting health? '))
X = health / time_of_activity 

def healthdecrease():
   i = 1
   while i<(time_of_activity):
    time.sleep(1)
    i+=1
    health = health - X

decrease_of_health = threading.Thread(target=healthdecrease)
decrease_of_health.start()
```

That is the code I have so far. It seems to be missing something, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: and what seems to be the issue?

Comment: Like this `health` is only updated in the namespace of the function.

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the `healthdecrease` function correctly. It should be like this:

```
decrease_of_health = threading.Thread(target=healthdecrease())
```

> I guess you can just do it like this:
>
> ```
> def healthdecrease():
>  while(health):
>    health -= x
> ```

Answer (score 0):

For the most part the logic of the code is correct, however there was no indication to python that `health` is a global variable. This must be done explicitly in the `health_decrease` method so that it uses the existing global variable rather than creating a new, local one.
Other than that, some of the formatting (more specifically, the indentation) was off.
Lastly, I added a `max()` component when subtracting `decrement` from `health` to ensure the value never goes below 0 due to floating point rounding errors.

Here is a functional code sample (without the threading):

```
import time

time_of_activity = float(input('How long should health decrease for in seconds? '))

health = float(input('What is the starting health? '))
decrement = health / time_of_activity 

def health_decrease():
    global health
    i = 1
    while i <= time_of_activity:
        time.sleep(1)
        i += 1
        health = max(health - decrement, 0)

health_decrease()
```